# Why does the position of scroll change when I append data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending the data not in same `div`. But when I append data, my focus or scroll position goes in between the append content. Actually I am appending the data when user scroll to bottom.
But when I save google images, it loads some images then when user goes to last lines it loads more images without changing the scroll position.

Can we do in my example
http://jsfiddle.net/cQ75J/10/

```
 var pages = [page_1, page_2, page_3, page_4, page_5];
    var backupPages=new Array();
    var totalPage = "page_" + pages.length;
    $("#current").html(pages.pop());


$("#fullContainer").scroll(function () {

     if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight - document.body.offsetHeight && pages.length) {
          // alert("--")
          $("#next").html('')
        $("#pre").html('')
        $("#pre").html($("#current").html());
        $("#current").html('');

        $(this).scrollTop(
           $("#current").html(pages.pop())
            .appendTo($("#fullContainer"))
            .height()
        );
        }

});
```

I have one example in which my need is same scrolling position after appending. But it create new `div` in current `div`. I need new data come in current(id) `div` and current data goes to previous(id) div
http://jsfiddle.net/hBvrA/

Comment: It scroll position change it goes some where in between the append data

Comment: please check my second fiddle it work fine but problem is that it create new divs

Comment: when you scroll my contend it append data in my current div .And focus or scroll position goes somewhere else .It should be on last line only

Comment: Please check my second fiddle .it work fine focus or scroll position  remain on same .But it create new divs

Comment: As you see on facebook app it load the chat but scroll position remain same ..

Answer (score 0):

check updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hBvrA/1/

I have created function to update html structure

```
function updateContents() {
    $("#pre").html($("#pre").html() + $("#current").html());
    $("#current").html("<div>" + pages.pop() + "</div>"); 
    $("#fullContainer").scrollTop($("#pre").height());
}
```

and called in scroll event with wait timer mechanism:

```
var timerWait = 1000;
var timerFlag = false;

$("#fullContainer").scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight - document.body.offsetHeight && pages.length) {
        // Clear timer
        clearTimeout(timerFlag);
        timerFlag = setTimeout(function() {
            updateContents(); 
        }, timerWait);
    }
});
```